# How to add Zeros in between a string

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have string and want to pad zero in between the strings  using sql

So if the string is like

ABC7 then ABC007

XYZ55 then XYZ055

PQR123 then PQR123

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Grab the first 3 characters with [`LEFT()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_LEFT.html), then `||` join with the [`SUBSTRING()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUBSTRING.html) starting at position 4 that is used with [`TO_NUMBER()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_TO_NUMBER.html), something like this:

```sql
SELECT
  LEFT(field, 3) || TO_NUMBER(SUBSTRING(field, 4), '009')
```

I didn't test it, so it might need some tweaking.